# Run GStreamer pipeline branches without synchronization

Tags: gstreamer, gstreamer-1.0

I have following pipeline. One branch is used to display video, second one uploads frames every second to the HTTP server.

```
gst-launch-1.0 -e \
    filesrc location=test.mp4 ! queue ! qtdemux name=d d.video_0 ! h264parse ! avdec_h264 ! tee name=t  \
                       t. ! queue ! videoscale ! 'video/x-raw,width=(int)640,height=(int)480' ! autovideosink  \
                       t. ! queue ! videorate ! 'video/x-raw,framerate=1/1' ! jpegenc ! curlhttpsink  \
                             location=http://192.168.100.150:8080/upload_picture  \
                             user=admin passwd=test  \
                             content-type=image/jpeg  \
                             use-content-length=false
```

Problem occurs in case server is unreachable or does not process uploads fast enough. In that case video playback will stop for the time it takes for upload branch to catch up. I would expect `tee` in combination with `queue` to allow video to run out of the queued buffers while queue in upload branch gets filled.

Is such *out of sync* behavior possible? I tried both `sync` and `async` properties but without desired result.

Comment: Note that a `queue` by default is limited to 1 second of data. Also a `queue` element has three different max sizes you can set. For bigger queues I would also considering at a place where the image data is not raw.

Comment: So your suggestion is to change second branch to something like this `t. ! videorate ! 'video/x-raw,framerate=1/1' ! jpegenc ! queue ! curlhttpsink` in order not to queue as much data?

Comment: This change improved the pipeline, video runs for few seconds, up to the point queue is filled I suppose. So this leads me to one question. Is there any synchronization between sinks or they just seems to wait for each other because of full queues?

Comment: They don't "wait", they simply starve..